# Trying to run tests on a cordapp but keep getting this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream is either empty or not a JAR/ZIP

Tags: corda

Whenever I try to launch my tests for the BNMS selfIssueMembershipFlowTest.kt workflow the test abruptly stops due problems which I believe might be attributed to quasar

For the run configuration I have set the "VM options" to "-ea -javaagent:bn-apps/lib/quasar.jar" and set the  "shorten command line" option to "JAR manifest"

```java
@Test
fun `self issue should fail if a membership state already exists`() {
   val bnoNode = bnoNodes.first()

   runSelfIssueMembershipFlow(bnoNode,bnoNode.identity())

   try {
     runSelfIssueMembershipFlow(bnoNode,bnoNode.identity())
     fail()
   } catch (e : FlowException) {
     assert("Membership already exists" == e.message)
   }
  }
}
```

The error messages I get is

> ```
> QUASAR WARNING: Assertions enabled. This may harm performance.
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream is either empty or not a JAR/ZIP
> at net.corda.node.services.persistence.NodeAttachmentService$Companion.checkIsAValidJAR(NodeAttachmentService.kt:86)
>   at net.corda.node.services.persistence.NodeAttachmentService$Companion.access$checkIsAValidJAR(NodeAttachmentService.kt:65)
>   at net.corda.node.services.persistence.NodeAttachmentService$import$1$1.invoke(NodeAttachmentService.kt:360)
>   at net.corda.node.services.persistence.NodeAttachmentService$import$1$1.invoke(NodeAttachmentService.kt:52)
>   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.ContractsScanningKt.withContractsInJar(ContractsScanning.kt:55)
>   at net.corda.node.services.persistence.NodeAttachmentService$import$1.invoke(NodeAttachmentService.kt:348)
>   at net.corda.node.services.persistence.NodeAttachmentService$import$1.invoke(NodeAttachmentService.kt:52)
>   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:236)
>   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:221)
>   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:199)
>   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:205)
>   at net.corda.node.services.persistence.NodeAttachmentService.import(NodeAttachmentService.kt:347)
>   at net.corda.node.services.persistence.NodeAttachmentService.privilegedImportAttachment(NodeAttachmentService.kt:299)
>   at com.r3.businessnetworks.membership.flows.AbstractFlowTest.setup(AbstractFlowTest.kt:68)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>   at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
> Process finished with exit code -1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that Corda can't recognize a file you uploading as a jar file. The error message wasn't very helpful, but it has been fixed [here](https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-2632?workflowName=Copy%20of%20Software%20Development&stepId=3).